# ¿Cómo mantengo estado de botón con LocalStorage JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un efecto de "Copos de nieve" con [Flurry JS](https://github.com/joshmcrty/Flurry) el cuál tiene sus dos métodos:

1. $("body").flurry();
2. $("body").flurry('destroy');

Estoy intentando agregar un botón tipo "apagador" que mantenga un "activo" o "desactivo" con [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) por si el usuario quiere tener o no el efecto de copos de nieve y que esté se guarde para reactivar después de un refresh en la página, les dejo mi código ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Botón "Apagador" (Realmente es un span con clase "modo_festejo"):

```
<span class="dropdown-item modo_festejo">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/25/null/confetti.png" class="align-text-center bg-transparent d-inline-block m-r-5" width="25" height="25" alt="Decoración"/>
    Decoración
</span>
```

El evento clic lo hago como selector de JQuery:

```
let botonFestivoPresionado = false;
$('.modo_festejo').click( (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (botonFestivoPresionado) {
        $('body').flurry('');
        localStorage.setItem('modoFestivo', 1);
        botonFestivoPresionado = false
    } else {
        if (modoFestivoLS === 0) {
            $('body').flurry('');
            localStorage.setItem('modoFestivo', 1);
        } else {
            $('body').flurry('destroy');
            localStorage.setItem('modoFestivo', 0);
            botonPresionado = true;
        }
    }
});
```

LocalStorage:

```
let modoFestivoLS = localStorage.getItem('modoFestivo');

function modoFestivo () {
    if (modoFestivoLS === 0) {
        $('body').flurry('destroy');
    } else {
        $('body').flurry();
    }
}
```

Y la función modoFestivo () la mando llamar desde dentro de:

```
$(document).ready( () => {
    modoFestivo();
});
```

Entiendo que es un falso o verdadero, después de ahí se valida si está encendido, no tiene caso "re encender" ¿Sí me explique?

Comment: Y, ¿cuál es el problema? ¿qué depuraciones has hecho y con qué resultados?

Answer (score 0):

Hola por lo que entiendo en el evento de onclick que realizas se debe validar que el valor de la acción determine si este encendido o no, con esta validación se realiza el seteo de la variable en el localStorage cumpliendo lo siguiente:

- Primero si el caso es verdadero debe inicializar `$("body").flurry();` este para inicializar el evento de animación
- Luego si es falso usar `$('body').flurry('destroy');` este permite apagar la animación.

Este último no es necesario usarlo si así lo deseas ya que si garantizas el encendido o apagado manual este ejecutara el `$('body').flurry('destroy');`.